# Is it possible to define a default value for a parameter function?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to define a default function as a parameter for another function in Kotlin? I know that we can define default values for objects but don't know how to do it for parameter functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambdas to define a default value for a functional parameter. Here's an example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    higherOrderFun()
    higherOrderFun { println("World")}
}

fun higherOrderFun(fn : () -> Unit = { println("Hello") }) {
    fn()
}
```